# Selenium Parallel execution

Tags: selenium, junit, parallel-processing, selenium-chromedriver

Hey guys i am running parallel operations in headless mode or without headless mode i get the same error, which are the following :

```
INFO: Using parallel execution mode 'CONCURRENT' set via the 'junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default' configuration parameter.

stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

stale element reference error is a WebDriver error that occurs because the referenced web element is no longer attached to the DOM. ... When an element is no longer attached to the DOM, i.e. it has been removed from the document or the document has changed, it is said to be stale

How can i fix this problem?

My test configs

```
test {
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled", true)
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default", "CONCURRENT")
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and my webdriver initialisation

```
 protected WebDriver driver;
    protected String TARGET_URL;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        loginToEnvironment();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
    }
```

Comment: Probably two parallel threads use the same driver hence one of the threads changes DOM state while another attempts to access the element through now stale reference.

Comment: @AlexeyR. thank you once again to attend my question, how can i resolve this situation

Comment: There is nothing looking suspicious in provided code. Probably the issue is a bit deeper like with the singleton case.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yeh i was about to mention, before each test new driver is created and if its parallel it should be different drivers for each test so that should not be the case, could suggest anything ? running test class without parallel execution goes through successfully

Comment: This is caused by using one WebDriver instance by two independent tests. Inside the @BeforeMethod you are creating a new instance by driver= new ChromeDriver();, but this replaces the field

private WebDriver driver;
by this instance. There is a new instance created by every thread, but only the last one is used - the one that is currently referenced by the private WebDriver driver field. I need to tell every test method to keep the separate WebDriver instance without using it as a class field somehow

Comment: @AlexeyR. i think i found an issue.. all the components are static fields so it looks like two thread sharing same instance.. but now i do not know how to approach it without breaking my singelton pattern approach